# Troubleshoot conversion failed when converting date and /or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I know this has been addressed 1000 times but something screwy is going on and I need help with ideas to troubleshoot.

Using MS SQL Server 2012
I have a date stored as INT in the YYYYMMDD format.

I need to turn that into a date and I always use this:
CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,YYYYMMDD),101)
*I know not specifying the length of the varchar is bad form but where I'm doing this has never caused an issue and just to be thorough I tried it anyway to no avail.

That conversion always works. Always, until today.

Today, this conversion doesn't work and I get the above mentioned error in title.

One thing I've done is run part of the query to look at the values to make sure I don't find something dumb like this in my values:

```
   20170102
   20170304
-->2017ABCD
   20170704
```

What else can I do?

Comment: Use Try_Convert() .. it will return a NULL when the conversion fails

Comment: @johncappelletti So this is interesting. I ran the query and everything converted normally under Try_convert() and I didn't get any nulls but if I drop the Try_ I get the 'conversion failed...' error.

Comment: Without seeing your actual query I can't explain your results.   Were the null records excluded elsewhere ... Like in a join?

Comment: Understandable. I have absolutely no idea. I am joining 2 tables that I have not joined before and I'm trying to understand how the join (which is very straightforward) could be causing an issue. The query works beautifully otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my initial comment

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('20170102'),
('20170304'),
('2017ABCD'),
('20170704')

Select SomeCol
      ,AsDate  = try_convert(date,SomeCol)
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol     AsDate
20170102    2017-01-02
20170304    2017-03-04
2017ABCD    NULL
20170704    2017-07-04
```